# jquery datatables actionlink how to add

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I have been searching for the last few hours, and unfortunately I cannot seem to find an example of how to populate a datatable with an action edit and delete link column using .net and MVC.

Here is what I have so far, how do I add an action link? What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("Index1", "Default1")'
    });

});
</script>

<div id="container">
<div id="demo">
    <table id="myDataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    RoleId
                </th>
                <th>
                    RoleName
                </th>
                <th>
                    UserId
                </th>
                <th>
                    UserName
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        </tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</div>
```

I want to add this in the last column;

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id=item.PrimaryKey}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PrimaryKey }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PrimaryKey })
    </td>
```

But cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `aoColumns` property with `fnRender` function to add custom columns.
You can't use the `Html.ActionLink` helper because you have to generate the links dynamically from the javascript. The `aoColumns` property helps you to configure each columns, if you don't want to configure a particular column just pass `null` else you have to pass an `object({})`.

The `fnRender` function helps you to create the links using the values of the other columns. You can use the `oObj.aData` to get the values of the other column like `id` to generate the links.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,         
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("Index1", "Default1")',
            aoColumns: [
                      null, // first column (RoleId)
                      null, // second column (RoleName)  
                      null, // third (UserId)
                      null, // fourth (UserName)

                      {     // fifth column (Edit link)
                        "sName": "RoleId",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj)                              
                        {
                            // oObj.aData[0] returns the RoleId
                            return "<a href='/Edit?id=" 
                                + oObj.aData[0] + "'>Edit</a>";
                        }
                       },

                       { }, // repeat the samething for the details link

                       { }  // repeat the samething for the delete link as well

                   ]
     });  
}); 
</script>
```

Another important thing in the JSON output you return from the server, for the edit column also you have to return something like 1, 2, 3 or anything.

Reference: http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajax-inlinebuttons.html

Comment: "fnRender" has been deprecated. Use "mRender" instead. http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns

Answer (score 7):

The fnRender has been depreciated and the mRender doesn't received the same parameters.

This works for me, follow the @Mark example:

```
  {     // fifth column (Edit link)
    "sName": "RoleId",
    "bSearchable": false,
    "bSortable": false,
    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
        var id = full[0]; //row id in the first column
        return "<a href='javascript:alert("+id+");'>Edit</a>";
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The other responses are using legacy DataTables syntax.  For DataTables 1.10+, the syntax for [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) is as follows:

```
$('#MyDataTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": '@Url.Action("Index1", "Default1")',
    "columnDefs": [
        {"targets": [4], "data": "RoleId", "render" : function(data, type, full) { return '@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = "replace"})'.replace("replace", data);}},
        {},  //repeat
        {}   //repeat
    ]
});
```

note:  In order to get the Model in the ActionLink, I'm using [JavaScript replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the string "replace" with `data`, which is defined as "RoleId" earlier in the columnDef

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with aoColumnDefs

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    bProcessing: true,
    sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("Index1", "Default1")'
    aoColumnDefs: [{
                     "aTargets": [4],    //Edit column
                     "mData": "RoleId",  //Get value from RoleId column, I assumed you used "RoleId" as the name for RoleId in your JSON, in my case, I didn't assigned any name in code behind so i used "mData": "0"
                     "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                       return '<a href=' +
                            '@Url.Action("Edit", "Default1")?RoleId=' + data +
                            '>Edit</a>';
                     }
                  },{
                     "aTargets": [5],    //Detail column
                     "mData": "RoleId",  
                     "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                       return '<a href=' +
                            '@Url.Action("Detail", "Default1")?RoleId=' + data +
                            '>Detail</a>';
                     }
                  },{
                     "aTargets": [6],    //Delete column
                     "mData": "RoleId",  
                     "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                       return '<a href=' +
                            '@Url.Action("Delete", "Default1")?RoleId=' + data +
                            '>Delete</a>';
                     }
                  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to get this actionlink works using help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091699/adding-ajax-actionlink-to-datatable-column-while-using-server-side-processing) (olivier comments):

you add data tags attributes in the table node that you reuse in the Javascript

in cshtml:

```
<table class="table table-striped display" id="list" 
            data-url-edit="@Url.Action("Edit","User", new { id = "replace"})"
```

in your *.js file in ths columndefs area:

```
  "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [-1], "data": "UserID", "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="' + $('#list').data('url-edit').replace("replace", row.UserID) + '">Edit</a> | '
                    + '<a href="' + $('#list').data('url-details').replace("replace", row.UserID) + '">Details</a> | '
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used mentioned code for datatable 1.10+ but get string in the datatable cell instead of the link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = "294"})
```

note that using and old mvc3 version on the solution
Here my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var tenantid = $('#tenantid').text();
$("#title").html("<h1>User List for TenantID: "+ tenantid + " </h1>");

var oTable = $('#list').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": '/User/DataHandler',
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'data': function (data)
        {
            data.ID = tenantid;
            return data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
    },
    "dom": 'lfrtiSp',        
    "processing": true,
    "paging": true,
    "deferRender": true,        
    "pageLength": 10,
    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    "columnDefs": [
        { "targets": [-1], "data": "UserID", "render": function (data, type, row, meta) { return '@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = "replace"})'.replace("replace", row.UserID); } }

    ],

    "columns": [
        { "data": "UserID", "orderable": true },
        { "data": "UserGUID", "orderable": false },
        { "data": "UserName", "orderable": true },
        { "data": "UserEMAil", "orderable": true },
        { "data": "UserIsDeleted", "orderable": true },
        { "data": "Action", "orderable": false }
    ],

    "order": [0, "asc"]

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

add this as your Edit / Action column

```
{ "data": "YOURIDKEYCOLUMN",
  "render": function (data) {
   return "<a href='/YOUREDITINGURL/Edit/"+data+"'>Edit</a>"
   }
```